# Dependencies not working well

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-data

I have a project, that's using spring-mvc and spring-data dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!--Database dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Basic spring dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Tests dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Web dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My classes:

Repository:

```
@Transactional
public interface MeetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Meeting, Long> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller@RequestMapping("/meetings")
public class MeetingController {


@Autowired
private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;


@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String helloWorld(Model model) {
    Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
    meeting.setAddedDate(new Date());
    meeting.setMeetingDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000)); //1 week later
    meeting.setNotes("My firt meeting.");
    meeting.setPlace("Room 200");

    meetingRepository.save(meeting);
    model.addAttribute("meeting", meeting);
    return "helloWorld2";
}
}
```

Config classes:

```
  @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    public class AppConfig {
    }

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.szymon.repository")
public class DataAccessConfig {

@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    localEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("postgres");
    return localEntityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.szymon.controller")
public class WebMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(container);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
}
}
```

When i trying to test repository:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataAccessConfig.class)
public class MeetingRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
        meeting.setAddedDate(new Date());
        meeting.setMeetingDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000));
        meeting.setNotes("My first meeting.");
        meeting.setPlace("Room 200");

        meetingRepository.save(meeting);
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }


}
```

Im getting weird error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.clearMetadataCache()V
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:185)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Also, if i try to conect to controller with localhost:8080/meetings/hello im getting error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.szymon.controller.MeetingController.helloWorld(MeetingController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

But most weird, is if I remove `spring-context` dependency then test is passing well, but controller getting different error, that he couldn't autowired some beans.

I'm new to Spring data, and spring mvc. I know how to write entities, controllers, and ropositories class, but I still have problem with configuration. Do you know why test works after removing that dependency, and why not working with it? And finally how to make it works all together?

Comment: I would check your versions if I were you.

Comment: @GermannArlington What do you mean? What should I looking for, to detect what's not working?

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: @PeterRader no, im using Intellij

Comment: Check dependencies versions compatibility between postgresql, org.hibernate and org.springframework.data (and maybe org.springframework) in your pom file.
Your errors look like being caused by incompatibility problems

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in intellij there is such a tree:
[image: dependency]

How to read such a tree? You will notice there is ehcache-spring-annotation (4th from bottom) requiring a previous version of slf4j-api (3rd from bottom in version 1.6.2). But a newer version of slf4j-api is hardcoded(1st from above).

Now, when slf4j in example having a method `clearMetadataCache` in version `1.6.1` that is removed in `1.6.6`, such a `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown.

Comment: This is not an answer, its an explaination what is sooo weird with `NoSuchMethodError`

Answer (score 0):

As the error log said Spring failed to autowire MeetingController because it cannot autowird MeetingRepository. So check the MeetingRepository implementation if you have added @Repository to make sure the Spring can autowire it, or make sure the Spring will scan the component package.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the Spring IO Platform, that should resolve the version issues regarding the spring dependencies.

For details see [enter link description here](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) .
Additionally either use spring-data-jpa or don't use it. I would use it, the spring-data repsitories are really simple and powerfull. The EntityManager dependency is in that case not necessary.